# Implementing dark theme windows in Mac app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, macos

How can I customize my mac app's windows to a 'dark theme' as seen in Facetime? I'm wondering if this is a setting in Interface Builder, or if I will have to use a custom gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to do it yourself, including the controls. You might use the transparent controls here: http://brandonwalkin.com/bwtoolkit/

Answer (score 1):

This type of window is also seen in Quicktime Player, but according to these:

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/May/msg00257.html

http://lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2011/May/msg00259.html

it isn't available as option.